# Manipulate data set column in r hadoop

Tags: rhadoop

I have a data set which have a date (1/10/2015, 1/10/2016, 1/10/2017). I want to change it's format like this (2015, 2016, 2017). I need to do this using Hadoop.

Comment: http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.se/2011/06/extract-date-in-required-formats-from.html MB this will help?

Comment: Have it helped? Should I create the answer, so you can vote/accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a regex expression to extract the required value.**

The good tutorial with examples could be found in this blog: [Extract date in required formats from hive tables](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.se/2011/06/extract-date-in-required-formats-from.html)

> If you want the year and month alone of the format ‘yyyy-MM’ then use
>   `regexp_extract(column_datetime,'(.*\-.*)\-.*',1)`

---

EDIT: Originally ^this^ was posted as the *comment*, but I wrapped it as the *answer*, so other people may find it quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
select regexp_replace('1/10/2015, 1/10/2016, 1/10/2017','(\\d/\\d\\d/)','') rr
```